# Как принимать N количество сообщений от пользователя? Telegram API, Spring boot

Tags: java, telegram-bot, spring-boot

Не могу понять как заставить бота ждать ответ, или если говорить кратко, то ищу способ сделать сценарий из N-го количества ответов. Пример:

- Юзер: /add
- Бот: Введите название
- Юзер: test
- Бот: введите количество
- Юзер: 12

И так далее, думаю суть ясна. Проблема появляется уже во время первого ответа, так как если я буду писать логику в одном кейсе (add), то при следующем сообщении от юзера в **onUpdateReceived** оно не попадёт в тот же кейс **add**. Искал варианты, и много где говорили, что нужно запомнить состояние бота, но там по логике они могли принимать 1 ответ, а мне нужно N(>1). В Python есть библотека, которая помогает решить эту проблему, может быть в Java тоже. Если знаете - напишите, буду очень благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы сохранять состояния одного пользователя между запросами, используйте `SpringSecurity`    `session`. После авторизации сессия возвращается в заголовке и на стороне клиента может быть сохранена для дальнейшего использования.
Без `SpringSecurity` можно самому сделать имитацию сессии - при первом запросе в базе данных создать запись, для которой сгенерировать id сесии и туда же сложить данные из первого запроса. Этот идентификатор отправить в ответе фронтенду, и потом включить его второй запрос, тогда на бэкенде вы сможете из базы извлечь данные пришедшие с первым запросом соответствующие этой сессии

Comment: можно самому сделать имитацию сессии и хранить в базе данных (то есть при запросе в бд создавать сессию, данные относящиеся к ней сохранять, а в ответе отдавать id сессии).

Comment: а есть способ без SpringSecurity ?

Comment: Обновил ответ, можно самому сымитировать сессию

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с похожей проблемой, решил созданием базы данных H2, где создавал boolean колонки, где отмечал пройдённый этап, для каждого нового chatId. Их нужно сохранять сразу при первом контакте с пользователем, например при нажатии /start.

В вашем случае тоже можно ставить галочку после каждого ответа пользователя.

- Бот: Введите название
- Юзер: test

  ```
   -- UPDATE TABLENAME 
   -- SET is_user_send_name = true 
   -- WHERE chat_id='1111'

  findNextFalseFieldForUser()
  ```
- Бот: введите количество
- Юзер: 12

  ```
    -- UPDATE TABLENAME 
    -- SET is_user_send_count = true 
    -- WHERE chat_id='1111'
  ```

Решение кажется мне сомнительным, но оно работает.
Есть ещё интересная альтернативная библиотека:
https://github.com/pengrad/java-telegram-bot-api
Можно поискать варианты решения там. Как по мне она удобнее официальной.

Answer (score 0):

Есть два пути решения проблемы:

1. Найти готовое решение и его [использовать](https://github.com/rubenlagus/TelegramBots/wiki/State-Machines)
2. Реализовать самостоятельно [конечный автомат](https://habr.com/ru/articles/728196/) и хранить текущее состояние пользователя.